# Is this valid XML tagging?

Tags: xml, validation, syntax, tags

I had thought xml had to have a start & end tag, for example

```
<SalesRankings> 1 </SalesRankings>
```

but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Bln.jpg) is a jpg of my XML, where the above format is not followed. I pasted it into an XML validator & it didn't throw any errors, so is it valid?

```
<SalesRankings/>
```

Is the above Malformed XML or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid ([or rather, *well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/2998271)).

In the [`XML 1.0`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) specification, particularly section ***3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags***, this kind of element referenced as *empty-element tag*, which format defined formally as :

> [44]       EmptyElemTag       ::=      '<' [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) ([S](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S) [Attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Attribute))* [S](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S)? '/>'  [[WFC: Unique Att Spec]](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#uniqattspec)

Examples of empty elements from the spec :

```
<IMG align="left"
 src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/WWW/w3c_home" />
<br></br>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is called a "self-closing tag" - the vast majority of xml parsers will treat that as valid, exactly equivalent to "`<SalesRankings></SalesRankings>`".